# Evaluate the result of a method and get its value, if true, without calling it again

Tags: c#, if-statement, out

I'm using ZWCad APIs and .NET, C#

I need to evaluate if two segments intersect.

There is a method that does this and returns an array of points.

So I'm evaluating if this method returns null. If it does, then the segments don't intersect. If segment intersects then I need the instersection to do wathever.

This is the code I have.

```cs
if(segment.IntersectWith(segmentoEixo)!=null)
{
    Point3d[] intersectionPoints = segment.IntersectWith(segmentoEixo);

    // do something with this points
}
```

So I'm calling the `IntersectWith` method to evaluate if the segments intersect and calling it again if the lines do intersect.

I've researched and tried the `out` keyword but got anywhere with that.

Is there any other way to make this without calling the method twice?

Thanks

Comment: Make the assignment `Point3d[] intersectionPoints = segment.IntersectWith(segmentoEixo);` first, then check `if (intersectionPoints != null) { ...}`.

Comment: It's a little bit strange that you did not find out that you can create the variable `intersectionPoints` before the `if``. That's why variables exist. I suggest another coffee ;)

Comment: @TimSchmelter It looks that i'm a litle paranoic about initiating variables without realy needing it.. I'm not sure if coffee will help :)

Comment: @Clemens Of course :)

Comment: @solidWorking: 1. variables don't hurt, we have a garbage collector 2. you need it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option is through pattern matching:

```
if (segment.IntersectWith(segmentoEixo) is Point3d[] intersectionPoints)
{
    // do something with this points
}
```

If `segment.IntersectWith(segmentoEixo)` returns `null`, then the `Point3d[]` pattern will not be matched, and the condition will be false.

This also takes care of the `intersectionPoints` variable assignment.

Answer (score 4):

I may be missing the point completely, but why no do:

```
Point3d[] intersectionPoints = segment.IntersectWith(segmentoEixo);
if(intersectionPoints != null)
{
    // do something with this points
}
```

Explanation: instead of using a call just to check if there are no intersections, already store the result of that test, and work with the result if it's not equal to `null`

Comment: fvu It looks that i'm a litle paranoic about initiating variables without realy needing it. Of course, that solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Just additional to fvu's answer, that I absolutely second, and because you mentioned an attempt using the `out` keyword:

```cs
public bool TryIntersect(LineSegment3d segment, LineSegment3d segmentoEixo, out Point3D[] intersection)
{
    intersection = segment.IntersectWith(segmentoEixo);
    return intersection != null;
}
```

should work like this:

```
if ( TryIntersect( segment, segmentoEixo, out var intersection ) )
{
   // work with intersection here...
}
```

---

or as extension:

```cs
public static bool TryIntersectWith(this LineSegment3d segment, LineSegment3d segmentoEixo, out Point3D[] intersection)
{
    intersection = segment.IntersectWith(segmentoEixo);
    return intersection != null;
}
```

should work like this:

```
if ( segment.TryIntersectWith( segmentoEixo, out var intersection ) )
{
   // work with intersection here...
}
```

Comment: I would consider adding pattern matching option too. `if(segment.IntersectWith(segmentoEixo) is  Point3d[] intersectionPoints)` =)

Comment: Johnathan took care of that :)

Comment: @Fildor Just for precision `segment` and `segmentEixo` are `LineSegment3d`, not `Point3d[]`. I know that that's not obvious from OP, sorry for misleading you. Any way your answer is quite clear. Thanks.